# I do not understand phpmailer ERROR : Message was not sent..Mailer error: SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, email

Files from https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
ERROR : Message was not sent..Mailer error: SMTP connect() failed.

```
require_once('./class.phpmailer.php')
$mail = new PHPMailer()
$mail->IsSMTP() 
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
$mail->Port = "465"
$mail->SMTPAuth  = "true" 
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl"
$mail->Username = "mymail@gmail.com"
$mail->Password = "password"


//build the message
 $mail->IsHTML(true)
$mail->From     = "mymail@gmail.com"
$mail->AddAddress("mymail@mydomain.com")
$mail->Subject  = "An HTML Message"
$mail->Body     = "Hello, <b>my friend</b>! \n\n This message uses HTML entities!"

if($mail->Send()) {
  echo 'Message is sent'

} 
else {
  echo 'Message was not sent..'
 echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo
}
```

Comment: Your firewall blocks the port. Or you used the wrong port/protocol/etc.

Comment: open command line (cmd.exe) and try connect by telnet : telnet smtp.gmail.com 465

Answer (score 0):

You must enable OpenSSL. For example, in php.ini, remove the ';' on the line :

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

For view if you have enable "OpenSSL", create a new php file, put this in :

```
<?php echo phpinfo();?>
```

An looking for this information :

```
OpenSSL support :   enabled
```

-----ADD Complete Code-------------

I've test this code and it's running for me :

```
<?php
require_once('./class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP() ;
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth  = true ;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Username = "mymail@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "mypassword";


//build the message
 $mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->From     = "mymail@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress("mymail@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject  = "An HTML Message";
$mail->Body     = "Hello, <b>my friend</b>! \n\n This message uses HTML entities!";

if($mail->Send()) {
  echo 'Message is sent';

} 
else {
  echo 'Message was not sent..';
 echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

All the file if you need :

```
http://blog.portekoi.com/stack/Mailer.zip
```

Comment: (sorry I'm not good at English)
Thanks you.
I emailed it.
but Up to host this.
Message was not sent..Mailer error: SMTP connect() failed.

Comment: Check if you have OpenSSL.